# TCL script Need Help to Optimise If and also Correction of the 3rd Output

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I have the following code, and would like to know how to:

1) Optimise the "if", so in future if I have 10 new customer_id, I don't have to write 10 time the if-then-else statement, any suggestion?

2) Notice the output for no.3 its wrong, it should not be calculating (divide 1.5) how do I correct it?

**TCL Source Script**

```
set VG01 0
set VT01 0
set VG02 0
set VT02 0
set VG03 0
set VT03 0
set VGtable01 150
set VTtable01 15
set VGtable02 250
set VTtable02 25
set VGtable03 350
set VTtable03 35
set sCompareCustomerID01 "0001"
set sCompareCustomerID02 "0002"
set sCompareCustomerID03 "0003"
set sCustomer01 "0001"
set sCustomer02 "0002"
set sCustomer03 "0004"

if {[string compare $sCompareCustomerID01 $sCustomer01 ] == 0 ||
    [string compare $sCompareCustomerID02 $sCustomer02 ] == 0 ||
    [string compare $sCompareCustomerID03 $sCustomer03 ] == 0 } {
    set VG01 [expr $VGtable01 / 1.5]
    set VT01 [expr $VTtable01 / 1.5]
    set VG02 [expr $VGtable02 / 1.5]
    set VT02 [expr $VTtable02 / 1.5]
    set VG03 [expr $VGtable03 / 1.5]
    set VT03 [expr $VTtable03 / 1.5]
} else {
    set VG01 $VGtable01
    set VT01 $VTtable01
    set VG02 $VGtable02
    set VT02 $VTtable02
    set VG03 $VGtable03
    set VT03 $VTtable03
}

puts  "Target Value_Group 01: $VG01"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 01: $VT01"
puts  "Target Value_Group 02: $VG02"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 02: $VT02"
puts  "Target Value_Group 03 : $VG03"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 03: $VT03"
```

**============**

**Output:**

> Import started at 26 Mar 2020 04:09:58.
>
> ---
>
> Loading Script DLL
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Cubeware\cwscript85.dll
>   MMM-2020
>
> ---
>
> 200325_test division 1.5: Starting jobs at 26 Mar 2020 04:09:58
>   Execute script: 200325_test division 1.5 - Started at 26 Mar 2020 04:09:58
>
> ```
> Target Value_Group 01: 100.0 
> Target Value_Transaction 01: 10.0 
> Target Value_Group 02: 166.6666666666667 
> Target Value_Transaction 02: 16.66666666666667 
> Target Value_Group 03 : 233.3333333333333      < ------ this should be 350, no calculation require
> Target Value_Transaction 03: 23.33333333333333 < ------ this should be 35, no calculation require
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Freeing resources
>   Import completed
>   Import finished at 26 Mar 2020 04:09:58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you have only a single `if` and it looks like you should really have one separate `if` for each customer. To fix the issue alone, it would have to be:

```
if {[string compare $sCompareCustomerID01 $sCustomer01 ] == 0} {
    set VG01 [expr $VGtable01 / 1.5]
    set VT01 [expr $VTtable01 / 1.5]
} else {
    set VG01 $VGtable01
    set VT01 $VTtable01
}

if {[string compare $sCompareCustomerID02 $sCustomer02 ] == 0} {
    set VG02 [expr $VGtable02 / 1.5]
    set VT02 [expr $VTtable02 / 1.5]
} else {
    set VG02 $VGtable02
    set VT02 $VTtable02
}

if {[string compare $sCompareCustomerID03 $sCustomer03 ] == 0} {
    set VG03 [expr $VGtable03 / 1.5]
    set VT03 [expr $VTtable03 / 1.5]
} else {
    set VG03 $VGtable03
    set VT03 $VTtable03
}
```

But that's not really scalable. If you have more customers, I'd suggest using arrays instead of plain variables, for which then a loop can be used with a single `if`:

```
array set VG {
    01 0
    02 0
    03 0
}

array set VT {
    01 0
    02 0
    03 0
}

array set VGtable {
    01 150
    02 250
    03 350
}

array set VTtable {
    01 15
    02 25
    03 35
}

array set sCompareCustomerID {
    01 0001
    02 0002
    03 0003
}

array set sCustomer {
    01 0001
    02 0002
    03 0004
}

foreach customer [array names sCompareCustomerID] {
    if {
        [info exists sCustomer($customer)] && 
        [string compare $sCompareCustomerID($customer) $sCustomer($customer)] == 0
    } {
        set VG($customer) [expr {$VGtable($customer) / 1.5}]
        set VT($customer) [expr {$VTtable($customer) / 1.5}]
    } else {
        set VG($customer) $VGtable($customer)
        set VT($customer) $VTtable($customer)
    }
}

puts  "Target Value_Group 01: $VG(01)"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 01: $VT(01)"
puts  "Target Value_Group 02: $VG(02)"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 02: $VT(02)"
puts  "Target Value_Group 03 : $VG(03)"
puts  "Target Value_Transaction 03: $VT(03)"
```

Comment: Thank you Jerry for the expertise help, much appreciated, this help solved all the issue listed.